# SQL Server 2008 select top 100 defined by a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to select top @top defining the value by a variable like the following code in SQL Server 2008?

```
declare @top as integer;
set @top=100;

SELECT top @top
    T1.id as clientInfoId
    ,T1.ucsId
    ,T1.phoneHome
    ... (more columns here)......
    ,T1.businessTitle
FROM
    YELLOW_OUT_CLIENT_INFO AS T1    
LEFT JOIN 
    YELLOW_OUT_BUSINESS T2 on T2.clientInfoId = T1.id
WHERE
    T1.AgentId=5
    AND 
    T1.deleted IS NULL
    ... (more conditions here)......
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the variable in parentheses:

```
SELECT top (@top)
```

[This functionality was added in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)... 2000 was the last version that you had to do the `SET ROWCOUNT @top`

Comment: Madness. When was that added?

Comment: @Yuck SQL Server 2005 I believe...  [Example "A" gives a demo...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: The parentheses work with other commands too, like `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.